# Return array from db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure with a left join that returns something like this:

```
name1  car1
name1  car2
name1  car3
name2  car1
name3  null
name4  null
```

I need to store this result in an object like this:

```
class Person 
{
    string Name;
    List<string> Cars;
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Either directly in the stored procedure or in code after retrieving the query result.

That I do now is once I have the result from db to iterate over it and add the name and its list of cars c#to another object if name is not already there.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: What data access technology are you using? Can you provide some code of how you execute the stored procedure?

Comment: I am using Dapper, calling it like this var queryResult = PersonRepo.ExecuteQuery<PersonInfo>("dbo.GetPersonsCars", null, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList(). PersonInfo class is like Person class listed above but Cars is not a list, but simple a string. So I have to create 2 classes..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a DataReader returning the join results I'd do this:

```
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> people = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(0);
            string car = reader.GetString(1);
            List<string> cars = null;
            if (!people.TryGetValue(name, out cars))
            {
                people[name] = cars = new List<string>();
            }
            if (null != car)
                cars.Add(car);
        }
```

Each dictionary key/value pair represents a Person.  But you could create instances of Person now from the dictionary entries if you still need them.  I would just use the dictionary to access the people and their cars.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a more reusable DataAccess class that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, always. Depending on your requirements, you might/might not want to call `.ToList()` to force enumeration.

Then you can do whatever you want, like converting the `IEnumerable<T>` to whatever you need like `IDictionary<string, List<string>>`, or perhaps use the `.GroupBy()` LINQ method which may satisfy your requirements also.

You've got options, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two tables in your database. `Person` and `Cars`.
For simplicity assume Person to have two columns `PersonID, Name`, while Cars has three columns `CarID, Name, PersonID`. The field PersonID in the Cars table is the foreing key that links a car to a person.

A simple query that associates your Person to your Car is

```
string query = @"
SELECT p.PersonID, p.Name, c.CarID, c.Name 
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN Cars c on p.PersonID = c.PersonID";
```

and this could be your Model

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}
public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PersonID {get;set;}
}
```

Now you could write this to work with Dapper

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
using (IDbConnection cnn = GetOpenConnection())
{
    var people = cnn.Query <Person, Car, Person>(query, (per, car) =>
    {
        Person found;
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(per.PersonID, out found))
        {
            found = per;
            lookup.Add(per.PersonID, found);
            found.Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
        found.Cars.Add(car);
        return found;
    }, splitOn: "CarID").Distinct();
}
```